# vuetify data-table not showing data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-tables-2, v-data-table

i'm calling an API and storing the data into an array ( users[] ), and i can see in the
console that users[] is being populated, but the `data-table` is not
showing any rows.

```
<template>
<v-data-table
 :headers="headers"
 :items="users"
 class="elevation-1"
 :dark="true"
>

<template v-slot:item.deaths="{ item }">
  <v-chip :color="getColor(item.deaths)" dark>{{ item.deaths }}</v-chip>
</template>

<script>
 export default {

  data () {
   return {

   indiaTotalCase: null,
   indianDeaths: null,
   indianDischarged: null,

   headers: [
      { text: 'State', align: 'start', sortable: false, value: 'loc'},
      { text: 'Cases', value: 'totalConfirmed' },
      { text: 'Deaths', value: 'deaths' },
      { text: 'Discharged', value: 'discharged' } 
   ],
   users: [],
   }
  },

  mounted(){
     this.getdata();
     console.log("call finished");
  },

  methods: {
     getColor (deaths) {
      if (deaths > 100) return 'red'
      else if (deaths > 50) return 'orange'
      else return 'green'
     },

     getdata() {
        this.$http.get('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest')
          .then(response =>{
           return response.json();
           })

           .then(res =>{
             const data = res.data;
             this.indiaTotalCase = data.summary.total;
             this.indianDeaths = data.summary.deaths;
             this.indianDischarged = data.summary.discharged;
             const regionalData = data.regional;

           for(let index in regionalData){
             this.users[index] = regionalData[index];
           }

         });
        }
       },

</script>
```

i'm new to vue and sorry for bad formatting of the code.
this is the output which i'm getting. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GMzT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify getdata method as below and it should work

```
      getdata() {
  this.$http.get('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest')
  //  .then(response =>{
  //    return response.json();
  //  })
    .then(res =>{
       console.log('api res ',res)
      const data = res.body.data;
      this.indiaTotalCase = data.summary.total;
      this.indianDeaths = data.summary.deaths;
      this.indianDischarged = data.summary.discharged;
      const regionalData = data.regional;
      //  for(let index in regionalData){
      //    this.users[index] = regionalData[index];
      // }
      this.users = regionalData;
    });
```